# Run Azure function with Azure data factory to read and process files from blob

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have written an azure function that does some processing on data(converts unstructured to structured).

In my azure data factory,I have a pipeline which extracts files from a blob storage container to another container with a blob created event trigger.

I want to be able to integrate my azure function with the pipeline so that I am able to pass each file into the function for it to get processed.

I have found a way to do it by blob triggering the azure function also but I want to process the files by having the file path for each file as I only want some certain files to be processed from the blob store  container and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The [event trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger) includes the Blob folderPath and fileName, which you can reference by mapping the *@triggerBody().folderPath* and *@triggerBody().fileName* expressions to parameters. Once you have a handle on those values, you can determine whether or not you want to process them with an [If Condition activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity), and then use them to an [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).

Comment: The trigger body is for the directory containing the zip file. I want to have path for the extracted files in a different container.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your request. If your pipeline is doing the extraction to the source container, you should already know the path of the extracted files. What am I missing?